# Derivation of Navier’s Equations in Cylindrical Coordinates from First Principles

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been studying elasticity theory and came across the equilibrium equations in a cylindrical coordinate system expressed using Navier’s equations. The equations are given by:
$$
\begin{align}
&\nabla ^{2}u+\frac{1}{1-2\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{u}{r} +\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)-\frac{u}{r^{2}}-\frac{2}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \theta}=0\\
& \nabla ^{2}u+\frac{1}{1-2\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{u}{r} +\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)-\frac{u}{r^{2}}-\frac{2}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}=0\\
&\nabla ^{2}u+\frac{1}{1-2\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{u}{r} +\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)=0.
\end{align}
$$
where

- $\nabla ^{2}=\left( \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}}\right)$ is the Laplace operator in a cylindrical coordinate system,
- $\nu$ is the Poisson’s ratio,
- $u, v, w$ displacement components in the $r$-, $\theta$-, and $z$-directions of the cylindrical coordinate system,

I'm looking to understand how these equations are derived from first principles. Can someone guide me through the process or recommend any resources that tackle this derivation step-by-step?

Also, if there are any assumptions or specific conditions under which these equations hold, I'd like to know about them.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: "*When posting math-heavy content on many forums, it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with their specific LaTeX formatting rules (if they support it) so that your equations are displayed clearly. The use of LaTeX ensures that complex mathematical notations are readable and well-formatted for those who are viewing your question*."

This was left out so I reposted it as a comment.

Comment: Please check your equations. $\nabla ^{2}u+\frac{1}{1-2\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{u}{r} +\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)$ appears in all of them, and I suspect $\frac{\partial\nu}{\partial\theta}$ should be $\frac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630493/navier-stokes-equation-in-cylindrical-coordinates?rq=1.